# pip pyinstaller Connection Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, pip, pyinstaller

It occurs when trying
"pip install pyinstaller" on cmd.exe

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22jVb.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw1aE.png

Any ideas? 
I think the internet's behind proxy. I've tried all answers in similar asked questions, but none worked for me.

Comment: Post the text, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: You may be behind a firewall, this happened at my work.  To get around it you need to set the proxy server

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall, and have you created a system variable for python?

Answer (score 0):

open a command window and set the proxy server

```
set http_proxy=http://NTID:NTPassword@proxyserver:8080
set https_proxy=https://NTID:NTPassword@proxyserver:8080
```

Or download the wheel and install it with pip from the download location
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/